# Show $[6,3]$ quaternary code $\mathcal{G}_6$ is self-dual.

Tags: coding-theory

> The $[6,3]$ quaternary code $\mathcal{G}_6$ has generator matrix $G_6$ in standard form given by 
>       $G_6=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \omega & \omega\\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & \omega & 1 & \omega\\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & \omega & \omega & 1
>  \end{array}\right]$. Show $\mathcal{G}_6$ is self-dual.

---

As $G_6$ is generator matrix of $\mathcal{G}_6$, $G$ is parity check matrix for $\mathcal{G}_6^{\bot}$. Also $\mathcal{G}_6,\mathcal{G}_6^{\bot}$ both are $3\times 6$ matrix. So far, I just gather all information from definitions and propositions from the book. I stuck at this step as I don't quite see any information that I can use to show $\mathcal{G}_6$ is self dual.

---

I found a similar question [Self-Dual Code; generator matrix and parity check matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138984/self-dual-code-generator-matrix-and-parity-check-matrix), but I don't quite understand the answer. Can someone explain the answer in more detial or give me a hint to keep going to work on the question? Thanks.

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: @GitGud I don't know, the question doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: The code is quaternary. That means that the alphabet has size four. Because self-duality is discussed, the alphabet is at least a ring, most likely a field. I'm willing to wager that the alphabet here is $GF(4)$ aka $\Bbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\omega,\omega+1=\omega^2\}$.

Comment: Anyway. It is obvious that $G_6$ has the correct size and rank. All you need to is to show that its rows are orthogonal to themselves and each other. In other words: calculate the 3x3 matrix $G_6G_6^T$, and check that you get all zeros.

Comment: And, if you don't know what $\omega$ is and how you do arithmetic in $GF(4)$, you need to work on that first. Luckily that is not difficult at all. It is characteristic two, meaning that $\omega+\omega=0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why $G_6G_6^T=[0]$ is enough to show self-dual.

Comment: $G_6$ has rank $3$, so its rows generate a 3-dimensional code $C$. Because $3=6-3$ we know that the dual code $C^\perp$ is also 3-dimensional. So if we can show that $C\subseteq C^\perp$, then we can conclude that $C=C^\perp$ (a proper subspace has a lower dimension). And $G_6G_6^T=0_{3\times 3}$  (if it holds, I didn't check) implies exactly that $C\subseteq C^\perp$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much. That is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that my educated guess about the alphabet being $GF(4)=\{0,1,\omega,\omega+1=\omega^2\}$ is correct, then the claim is false as stated.

The inner product of the 1st and 2nd rows is
$$
0+0+0+\omega+\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2\neq0.
$$
Therefore not all words of $C$ are orthogonal to all the others.

The same holds for any pair of distinct rows of $G$.

---

So please check the source of the question, and give us more of context.
The same calculation (more or less) shows that the resulting code **is** self-dual, if the alphabet is the ring of binary dual numbers $\Bbb{Z}_2[\omega]$, with $\omega+\omega=0=\omega^2$. I would need to check the source to see whether that is a live possibility. Such rings have been proposed and studied.

Comment: I checked the textbook, your guess is correct.